# Microsoft TTS voice tone

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Is it possible to set the tone or emphasis of a specific word or phrase?

Eg: `Good Morning` would be in a relaxed voice, whereas `The nuclear plant is about to melt down` would be far more urgent.

I'm aware I can change the speed of playback but is there something more clever I'm not aware of? Do other TTS engines support this (and are any of them open-source)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using VoiceXML for the application?  Regardless, if the TTS engine support the SSML standard you should be able to use the [emphasis tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.2.2) which will indicate that the TTS engine should put emphasis on the phrase within the tag.  You are probably controlling the speed with the prosody tag which is also part of SSML.

Check out this [online demo for Loquendo TTS](http://www.loquendo.com/en/demo-center/interactive-tts-demo/).  It provides more expression based on punctuation and allows you to insert items like yawns, sneezes and laughing.  I think it is one of the better TTS engines out there, and Nuance must have thought so also because they just acquired them.  It is not open source though.

Voxeo provides a free TTS engine on their Prophecy IVR which supports the emphasis tag. There are several open source TTS engines available but they will not be as rich or sound nearly as good as something like Loquendo.  Just see if they support SSML.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I thought there was something like that floating around. I'm currently using the TTS engine that comes with Windows7/is default in .Net System.Speech namespace. All I know is that it's SAPI 5.3 compliant

Comment: Hmmm Loquendo seems to have been bought out by nuance. Do you happen to know if/where they have pricing information? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Go to Contacts on the Loquendo website and click "Store".  It already takes you to Nuance website.  There is pricing for Dragon Naturally Speaking but I did not see any for Loquendo TTS.  Probably restructuring pricing after the acquisition.  But if you hang out on that page you will get an instant chat window that comes up.  You can chat with one of their reps to get pricing or give them a call.

Comment: I did find this on MSDN about the Microsoft TTS Engine: "SAPI 5.3 supports the W3C Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) version 1.0, which is defined at http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis. SSML provides the ability to markup voice characteristics, speed, volume, pitch, emphasis, and pronunciation, so that developers can make TTS sound more natural in their applications."

Comment: For anyone else reading this, the key method for .Net is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.promptbuilder.startstyle.aspx